# Svelte todo app bug: new todos id property is never greater than 2

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am working on a small ToDo application in Svelte for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

I have this code for adding a new todo:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
      
    let todos = [];
      
    onMount(async function() {
        todos.reverse();
    });
      
    function addTodo() {
        //Empty todo object
        let newTodo = {};
      
        //Set new todo object's properties (id, title, completed)
        if (todos.length == 0) {
            newTodo.id = 1;
        } else {
            newTodo.id = todos[todos.length - 1].id + 1;
        }
        newTodo.title = document.querySelector('#new_todo').value;
        newTodo.completed = false;
      
        //Add new todo at the beginning of the array
        todos.unshift(newTodo);
      
        todos = todos;
    }
</script>

<div class="input-group p-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_todo">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button on:click="{addTodo}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For a reason I was unable to find - the maximum id of my todos is 2 - no meter how many I add.

See the REPL **[here](https://svelte.dev/repl/12cb6530a9bd46729751762e9979b610?version=3.23.2)**.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but it's really simple: `todos[todos.length - 1].id`, which is the id of the *last* todo in the list, always returns `1`, because you `unshift()` the new todos. Just take the first one: `todos[0].id + 1`, and it will work as you want.

Comment: Just to be more precise, I'm talking about line 22 in your demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems complicated and brittle to me, why not just remember the last insert ID?

```js
// ...
    
let todos = [];
let lastInsertId = 0;
    
function addTodo(){
    //Empty todo object
    let newTodo = {};
        
    //Set new todo object's properties (id, title, completed)
    newTodo.id = ++lastInsertId;
    newTodo.title = document.querySelector('#new_todo').value;
    newTodo.completed = false;
        
    //Add new todo at the behining
    todos.unshift(newTodo);
    todos = todos;
}

// ...
```

Also why `unshift()` and `reverse()` instead of just not reversing and pushing onto the list?

Comment: I need to assign and incremented if to the todos. I also need to display them newest first.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
newTodo.id = todos[todos.length - 1].id + 1;
```

to

```
newTodo.id = todos[0].id + 1;
```

since your first todos have the greatest id, not the last.